# setting cross-subdomain cookie with javascript

Tags: javascript, setcookie

How should I add domain support to [these](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script) functions? I want to achieve that .example.com is declared as domain, so that the cookies can be read across all subdomains of the example.com. In its current form since domain is not set, it can only be read from www.example.com

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Here is a link on how to share cookies amongst a domain:

https://www.thoughtco.com/javascript-by-example-2037272

It involves setting the domain attribute of the cookie string like:

```
document.cookie = "myValue=5;path=/;domain=example.com";
```

This cookie should now be accessible to all sub domains of example.com like login.example.com

Comment: the syntax of ppk's function seems to be different because it gets its name and expiry from its lines above: document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"; what about these double quotes?

Comment: @newnomad: JavaScript uses quotes around string literals like most programming languages.

Comment: this cant be added to cookies if I dont escape() it. but if escape - value set with path and domain

Comment: I was having a similar problem, and although I was putting in a leading dot before the domain name (in order for it to be available to another subdomain), it wasn't showing until I added the path=/ portion.

Comment: The link doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 3):

In my case we needed to set a cookie that would work across our .com subdomains:

```
function setCrossSubdomainCookie(name, value, days) {
  const assign = name + "=" + escape(value) + ";";
  const d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
  const expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString() + ";";
  const path = "path=/;";
  const domain = "domain=" + (document.domain.match(/[^\.]*\.[^.]*$/)[0]) + ";";
  document.cookie = assign + expires + path + domain;
}
```

This might not work for .co.uk etc but the principle can be used

Comment: How would I modify this to work with .co.uk as well? Assuming it needs some regex changing