# Save cookies with javascript how to specify domain?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to save cookies:

```
function saveCookie(name,value) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(60*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
        }
```

My problem is that it saves the cookie with domain "example.com" and I want to write them to ".example.com" so I can also read them from subdomains. This is easy to do with PHP but I don't know how to do it with javascript. How can I add a dot before the domain when I save the cookie?

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting cross-subdomain cookie with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713019/setting-cross-subdomain-cookie-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have `path` in there, `domain` is specified in the same way.

Comment: `path=/; domain=."+window.location.host;` ?

Answer (score 0):

To permit reading from other sub-domains, try:

```
'; path=/; domain=.'+window.location.host;
```