# make cookie persist across subdomain

Tags: javascript, cookies, subdomain

I set a cookie:

```
<script>
  document.cookie="cid1={{utm_campaign}}; path=/;"
</script>
```

The {{}} is a macro and is Google-Tag-Manager syntax, please ignore that.

The script above is triggered whenever anyone lands on example.com with a tag like so: example.com/?utm_medium=test&utm_source=bla&utm_campaign=foo. I tested it and sure enough, when I land on the home page with these parameters the cookie is set.

But a visitor can move to a subdomain dogs.example.com. When I looked in the console the cookie cid1 is no longer there.

Is there a setting I can change when creating the cookie other than setting the path to "/" so that the cookie crosses to the subdomain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Domain should be something like .example.com so *.example.com can access it

```
var website_host = window.location.hostname.replace('www.', '');
document.cookie = "cid1={{utm_campaign}}; path=/;domain=."+website_host 

// to be something like this"cid1={{utm_campaign}}; path=/;domain=.example.com"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer this was really easy. For the record I did search Google and Stack Overflow first but there was no results for a baby step like this, only more advanced cookie usage. Accepting shortly

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the domain-parameter for this. Set domain to `.example.com` to make it accessable from all pages in `.example.com`.

```
<script>
  document.cookie="cid1={{utm_campaign}}; path=/; domain=.example.com"
</script>
```

Duplicate here: [setting cross-subdomain cookie with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4713019/3355350)

> ;domain=domain (e.g., 'example.com', '.example.com' (includes all
>   subdomains), 'subdomain.example.com') If not specified, defaults to
>   the host portion of the current document location.

Full documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: Thanks for the answer, accepting @mohamed's only due to timing. Cheers