# Unable to set cookie in subdomain for all subdomains

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to set a cookie using javascript in the subdomain and make it available for all subdomains but it doesn't get set unless I explicitly specify the subdomain or skip out the `domain` parameter entirely which only sets the cookie for that subdomain and can't be read by others.

I have taken a look at [setting cross-subdomain cookie with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713019/setting-cross-subdomain-cookie-with-javascript) as well as [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain/23086139#23086139) and also https://www.thoughtco.com/javascript-by-example-2037272 which describe the exact method I've tried but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is the code I have currently running but doesn't work, the current subdomain I am trying it on is admin.example.com and would like to get the same cookie on web.example.com

`document.cookie = auth-cookie=abc; expires=Wed, 08 Jul 2020 12:30:55 GMT; path=/; domain=example.com;`

If I try either of the following code from admin, the cookie does get set but I am not able to access it in other sub domains

`document.cookie = auth-cookie=abc; expires=Wed, 08 Jul 2020 12:30:55 GMT; path=/;`
`document.cookie = auth-cookie=abc; expires=Wed, 08 Jul 2020 12:30:55 GMT; path=/; domain=admin.example.com;`

Comment: You can explicitly specify the domain name instead of the subdomain in the cookie

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on the answer or provide an example